# How to save Simple JWT Token in local storage using vue.js, vuex and django rest framework?

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, jwt, vuex

I have a problem to save JWT Token in Local Storage (or cookie). Now, when I refresh my page, I need to login again. When I POST to /api-token with username and password in response I've got access token and refresh token, and now, don't now how to store them and where.

My loginForm.vue:

```
(<form...)

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'LoginForm',
  data(){
      return{
          username: '',
          password: '',
      }
  },
  methods: {
      login(){
          this.$store.dispatch('userLogin', {
              username: this.username,
              password: this.password
          })
          .then(() => {
              this.$router.push({ name: 'home'})
          })
          .catch(err => {
              console.log(err)
        })
  }
}
}
</script>
```

and my store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { getAPI } from './api'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        accessToken: null,
        refreshToken: null,
    },
    mutations: {
        updateStorage (state, { access, refresh }) {
            state.accessToken = access
            state.refreshToken = refresh
        },
        destroyToken (state) {
            state.accessToken = null
            state.refreshToken = null
        }
    },
    getters: {
        loggedIn (state) {
            return state.accessToken != null
        }
    },
    actions: {
        userLogin (context, usercredentials){
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                getAPI.post('/api-token/', {
                    username: usercredentials.username,
                    password: usercredentials.password
                })
                .then(response => {
                    context.commit('updateStorage', {access: response.data.access, refresh: response.data.refresh})
                    resolve()
                })
            })
        },
        userLogout (context) {
            if (context.getters.loggedIn) {
                context.commit('destroyToken')
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I'm assuming I need to save them in local storage by store.js, after update and before destroy. Could you help me?

Comment: this problem is not related to vue , you can either save in localstorage or in cookie , i would prefer localstorage as cookie  shared between requests , increasing overhead 
read localstorage at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 6):

You need something like this:

You must save access token in default header's requests to auth user after every requests . also save token in localstorage:

```
axios.post('login', this.user)
.then(r=>
{
     axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + r.data.token;

     localStorage.setItem( 'token', JSON.stringify(r.data.token) );
}
```

and add to default headers on refresh: (top of main.js file)

```
let token = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('token') );
if( token ){
     window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
}
```

now you can send request from every component

Comment: what is `r.data.token` vs `r.token`? Is there a typo? Also, what is `window` ?

Answer (score 0):

> in the login page in (script) tag add this code

```
axios.post('/api/v1/token/login/', this.form)
.then((r) => {                    
 
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']='Bearer'+r.data.auth_token;
localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(r.data.auth_token));
})
```

and in the main.js add

```
let token = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('token') );
if( token ){
 window.axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token;
}
```